# Change Dates using Lag based on condition

Tags: sql, hive

Input Table :

```
date_1      date_2          ID
2019-01-01  2019-06-30      1
2019-05-01  2019-05-31      1
2019-06-01  2019-07-30      1
2019-01-02  2019-02-28      2
2019-03-01  2019-08-30      2
2019-01-02  2019-02-28      3
2019-02-06  2019-08-30      3
```

I am working on a complex HIVE problem of dates.
I need to changes dates of date_1 column and date_2 column for same ID.
I want to copy date_2's date to date_1's date in next row based on a condition. And all this I have to do for each ID, i.e. partition By ID.

Note : Data is sorted by ID asc, date_1 asc, date_2 asc.

For example :
Consider 2nd row, date_1 date is '2019-05-01' and now see its previous row for same ID 1 , here date_2 date is '2019-06-30'.
So check IF date_2 value of any row's previous row is greater than current row's value of date_1 , which is true in case of second row of ID 1.
When true then replace date_1 value of second row with date_2 value of previous row.
i.e. change 2019-05-01 to 2019-06-30, otherwise keep it as it is. Same do it for 3rd row and so on.
when considering 3rd row , then look for its previous row 2nd . And same goes for other rows.
Consider 2nd row of ID 2.
Here 2019-02-28is not greater than 2019-03-01 , so keep it as it is.

```
Expected Output :

date_1      date_2          ID
2019-01-01  2019-06-30      1
2019-06-30  2019-05-31      1
2019-06-01  2019-07-30      1
2019-01-02  2019-02-28      2
2019-03-01  2019-08-30      2
2019-01-02  2019-02-28      3
2019-02-28  2019-08-30      3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `lag()` like this

```
select date_add(lag(date2, 1, date1) over (partition by id order by date1), 1) as date1,
       date2,
       id
from t;
```